# Keep navigation bar in library webpart

Tags: sharepoint-server

When I add library WebPart I lose the navigation bar (A=>B) th ebreadcrumb

So how can I keep this bar? [image]

Comment: Do you mean the header links at the top of the page? This might be because you are in the "Edit" mode on the page? If you click the "Browse" ribbon those links should display again. -(would've left this as a comment before answering but not enough rep)

Comment: yes Calebben i mean the header links at the top of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added webpart to get folder and subfolders:
like this :
https://anothersharepointblog.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/sharepoint-document-library-list-view-view-web-part-with-clickable-breadcrumbs/

Answer (score 0):

For me when those links are hidden it means that a ribbon toolbar is selected. To view the page without this ribbon toolbar just click on the "Browse" ribbon highlighted below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an OOB way. You can inject a script that create a breadcrumb to enable you to navigate the folder structure.

You can find the code here:
https://github.com/RiccardoGDev/sp-breadcrumb

[image]